# Custom repository problems with Symfony2 - Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to move my query into a custom repository class. Here is what I've got so far

```
class MovieRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function showMovie($movie)
    {
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('m');

    $query = $qb->select('m.title', 'm.img', 'u.username')
        ->where('m.title = :movie')
        ->leftJoin('m.user', 'u')
        ->setParameter('movie', $movie)
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

I use it like this in my controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$result = $em->getRepository('AMovieBundle:Movie')->showMovie($movie);
```

I did put the @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="A\MovieBundle\Entity\MovieRepository") in my entity and the namespaces and folders are correct, and my relations from the movie to the user is correct as this worked before, when I had the query in the controller.

The primary error I keep getting is this:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symfony2test/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php line 271

Line 271 in the query builder is this:

```
public function getRootAlias()
{
    $aliases = $this->getRootAliases();
    return $aliases[0];
}
```

I have no idea where to go from here and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick tip, the function `getRootAlias()` returns the alias created for the query, which is in your case "m".

If i make an educated guess i'll try this (note the select syntax) :

```
$query = $qb->select('m.title, m.img, u.username')
            ->where('m.title = :movie')
            ->leftJoin('m.user', 'u')
            ->setParameter('movie', $movie)
            ->getQuery();
```

You are already inside an EntityRepository, you don't need to call `$this->getEntityManager()`.

Just do : 
`$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');`

That should fix your problem.

Comment: Good idea, I tried it but it didn't help my issue, still getting the same error. But it looks cleaner and I didn't know it was possible so I'll write my select syntax like that from now.